# get 'Undefined symbols for architecture armv7' error when integrate unity3d with vuforia into ios app

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I make all the step reference this [github repo](https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5). although i can solve some issue and error by myself, I finally get the error make me helpless. if someone have experience with integrate unity3D with vuforia into a ios swift app?

i will list the error I got

- lots of `use of undeclared identifier 'UIApplication'` and `failed to import bridging header '/Users/funkyLover/Desktop/ios-working-on/integrate/ios-unity/UnityBridge.h'`

solution: import `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` and `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` in `UnityBridge.h`

- ld: library not found for -lVuforia

solution: add `$(UNITY_IOS_EXPORT_PATH)/Libraries/Plugins/iOS` to `Library Search Paths`

and i final get the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Char::GetDataTablePointers(unsigned char const**, unsigned char const**, double const**, unsigned short const**, unsigned short const**, unsigned short const**, unsigned short const**)", referenced from:
      _Char_GetDataTablePointers_m2324968695 in Bulk_mscorlib_1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i have no idea about that error, please help

[reference issue](https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5/issues/17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is the same issue in unity3d forum and find the [solution](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/xcode-link-has-failed-since-5-3-5p1.425313/#post-2768616)

> c++ Language Dialect Option : Compiler Default -> C++ 11

it perfectly solve my problem in unity3d 5.4.0f3

btw, this issue seem cause by unity version, not the vuforia

Comment: I'm not able to fix the issue using this solution in unity version 5.6.1f1